# Why angular ngx effect doesn't work if it failed once?

Tags: angular, ngrx

i use angular 6 and Ngrx effects.
its a login effect

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
login$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Login>(AuthActionTypes.Login),
    tap(action => {
        localStorage.setItem(environment.authTokenKey, action.payload.authToken);
        console.log('login effect');
        this.store.dispatch(new UserRequested());
    }),
);
```

it dispatched user request effect

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
loadUser$ = this.actions$
.pipe(
    ofType<UserRequested>(AuthActionTypes.UserRequested),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(isUserLoaded))),
    filter(([action, _isUserLoaded]) => !_isUserLoaded),
    mergeMap(([action, _isUserLoaded]) => this.auth.getUserByToken()),
    tap(data => {
        console.log('login effect');
        if (data) {
            this.store.dispatch(new UserLoaded({ user: data['user'] }));
            localStorage.setItem('options', JSON.stringify(data['options']));
            // localStorage.setItem("permissions", data['user'].permissions_list);
            data['user'].permissions_list.forEach((item) => {
                this.permissionsService.addPermission(item.name);
            });
        } else {
            this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
        }
    }, error => {
        this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
    })
  );
```

If this effect was called and *FAILED AT LEAST ONCE TIME* before it wouldn't be called again. Why?

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/646#issuecomment-381437629

Answer (score 0):

Because streams need to be controled. If you stream has an error, it stops, as intended.

If you want it not to stop, consider using the `catchError` operator along with the `throwError` function, or simply catch the error in your subscribe.

See it live :

**not working**

```js
rxjs.throwError('mocked error')
  .subscribe(
    () => console.log('You should not see this message'),
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

**working**

```js
rxjs.throwError('mocked error')
  .subscribe(
    () => console.log('You should not see this message'),
    () => console.log('You should see this message')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

**working BIS**

```js
rxjs.throwError('mocked error')
  .pipe(rxjs.operators.catchError(err => rxjs.of('some mocked replacement value')))
  .subscribe(
    () => console.log('You should see this message'),
    () => console.log('You should not see this message')
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```